# Apply a four-point transform crop to an image

Tags: image-processing, image, geometric-transform, computer-vision

I am attempting to straighten and crop an image by using Edge Detection. The original image [looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYaSS.jpg). By using edge detection and finding the max and min values for the points regarding the corners, I am able to get  [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hmis.png).

However, I would like it to be perfectly straight, so that I can break it up into 10 (originally this was 20, but I realized 10 would suffice) perfect slices along the bars. Yes, I realize that I am currently only working with two points, but I would locate the coordinates of the other two points for the final version.

Is there a function that I can input all four corners into— have it crop the image according to those points, and have it transform the cropped image into a straightened rectangle of a given size?

Thank you very much in advance.

Here is the code I am currently working with:

```
i = Import["Images/1.JPG"]
corners = ImageCorners[i, 3, .01, 5]

minX = Min[corners[[;; , 1]]]
maxX = Max[corners[[;; , 1]]]
minY = Min[corners[[;; , 2]]]
maxY = Max[corners[[;; , 2]]]

z = ImageTrim[i, {{minX, minY}, {maxX, maxY}}]
imageData = ImagePartition[z, Scaled[{1/10, 1}]][[1, ;;]]

quantifyBar[x_] := Total[ImageMeasurements[x, "Mean"]]
classifyBar[x_] := If[x < 1.75, 1, 0]

For[x = 1, x < Length[imageData] + 1, x++,
 Print[classifyBar[quantifyBar[imageData[[x]]]]]]
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the code you have already tried (shown on your linked image)? This will improve the quality of the question.

Comment: Have you looked at `ImageTake`? You can specify rows and columns that you want to take from the image. Also I don't understand what you mean by straightened rectangle. Do you want to detect the edges and cut along them?

Comment: @Pinti Edited. Thank you.

Comment: @VahagnTumanyan I have yes, but Scaled's syntax looked more simple. My current attempt works the same, right? Sorry, after posting this question I ended up finding a better term for what I want— an affine transform on the photo, to create an orthogonal rectangle.